# Consulta left join con 6 tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tengo 6 tablas encuesta, form_alumnos, dimension, preguntas , tipo_respuesta, respuesta.

Tabla form_alumnos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas 

                    FROM encuesta e
              LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f ON e.id_encuesta = f.id_encuesta_for
              LEFT JOIN dimension d ON e.id_encuesta = d.id_encuesta_p
              LEFT JOIN preguntas p ON d.id_dimension = p.id_dimension_p
              LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
              LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo 
              WHERE f.cod_curso_alumno = '354196' AND f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer'

             GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo
```

y esa consulta me arroja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error de la consulta me muestra todos los datos y me los multiplica por 6, me debería mostrar solo los datos del cod_curso_alumno = '354196' , anio = '2016', semestre = 'Primer' y la consulta que quiero hacer debe quedar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ojalas alguien me puedan orientar, de antemano gracias

Comment: Me parece que lo que buscas basta con cambiar los left join por inner join, si no es así por favor se un poco más específico, pon un ejemplo de como sería un resultado aceptable.

Comment: Lo cambie pero no resulto, el resulta aceptable es lo que sale en la ultima foto eso es lo necesito. Hay 7 alumnos que contestaron las encuesta de los cuales 6 son de un curso 'INF6103' del año 2016 Primer semestre , entonces necesito hacer el filtro para ese curso en especifico para que genere los resultado(el resultado que me debería generar con ese filtro es la ultima imagen que subí)

Comment: cod_curso_alumno es int y tu lo estás subiendo como varchar, intenta en el WHERE así cod_curso_alumno = 354196

Comment: Los  resultados multiplicados en este caso indican un claro error en el diseño de las tablas... algún `JOIN` está trayendo datos de más. Eso es muy fácil saberlo. Empieza tu consulta por: `SELECT * FROM form_alumnos f WHERE f.cod_curso_alumno = '354196' AND f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer'`. ¿Ves los resultados que esperas en cuanto a cantidad de filas? Ahora agrega uno a uno los `JOIN` hasta que  los resultados se disloquen. Entonces sabrás que ese nuevo `JOIN` será el que tiene problemas. Las columnas `GROUP BY`  los vas agregando en la medida en que agregas sus tablas en el `JOIN`.

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpa la demora, seguí tu consejo revise las tablas y se ocurrió que en la tabla respuesta hacer otra fila id_form_alumno_fk(foranea de la tabla form_alumno) y coloque esta consulta

Comment: 'SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas   FROM preguntas p   LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
 LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo  LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno
                        
WHERE f.cod_curso_alumno = '354945' AND f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer'
 GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo '  
La cual me arroja lo que necesito, pero no me agrega los valores 0

Comment: No entiendo lo que quisiste decir en tu comentario Claudia.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres al decir *no me agrega los valores 0*? ¿Los valores `0` de que tabla y de qué columna?

Comment: que pude resolver mi problema pero a medias, la consulta me esta arrojando los datos que necesito, pero no me muestra los valores cuando son 0, ejemplo Esto me arroja
 Id_respuesta  tipo   cant_res
     1                   3          3
     1                  5           3

pero lo que necesito que arroje de esta manera:
d_respuesta  tipo   cant_res
     1                  1           0
    1                   2           0
     1                  3           3
     1                  4           0
     1                  5           3

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor editar tu pregunta poniendo los `CREATE TABLE` de cada tabla para hacer una prueba? ¿Tú quieres que te cuente los `id_respuesta` cierto? ¿Y hay casos en que no hay ningún `id_respuesta` en tus datos?

Comment: perdón era id_pregunta, si hay casos que no hay datos. Ejemplo hay 2 alumnos que respondieron la encuesta de 21 pregunta, supongamos que en la pregunta numero 1 el primer alumnos respondió tipo 5 y el segundo alumno respondió tipo 4, en la consulta que tengo lo cuenta de esta manera: en la pregunta 1 hay uno de tipo 4 y uno de tipo 5, lo que necesito es que me diga que en la pregunta 1 hay cero de tipo 1, cero de tipo 2, cero de tipo 3, 1 de tipo 4 y 1 de tipo 5.
Igual pongo los  **CREATE TABLE** ? igual son hartos datos

Answer (score 0):

El resultado se multiplica por cada registro que se asocie en las otras tablas, puede ampliar la funcion `GROUP BY` para agrupar los resultados como desee, por ejemplo, si desea agrupar **cod_curso_alumno**, **anio** y **semestre**, puede realizar la consulta asi:

`SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas 
FROM encuesta e
LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f ON e.id_encuesta = f.id_encuesta_for
LEFT JOIN dimension d ON e.id_encuesta = d.id_encuesta_p
LEFT JOIN preguntas p ON d.id_dimension = p.id_dimension_p
LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo 
WHERE f.cod_curso_alumno = '354196' 
AND f.anio = '2016' 
AND f.semestre = 'Primer'
GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, f.cod_curso_alumno, f.anio, f.semestre`

saludos.

Comment: gracias por responder,

lo hice pero me salio el mismo resultado y se sigue multiplicando, eso del cod_curso_alumno, anio, semestre es para filtrar y que me genere la tabla con los datos específicos de ese curso.