# Obtener todos los valores 0 en consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

estimados,

tengo un problema con una consulta porque no me muestra algunos datos con la consulta que tengo me muestra esta tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esa tabla no me mustra id_pregunta 2,6,16,17 tipo 3,3,3,3 cantidad_respuesta 0,0,0,0

la consulta que genera eso es la siguiente:

```
SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas
FROM preguntas p
LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta
LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo
LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno
WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '354945' AND f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer' or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL) 
AND (tr.tipo = '3')
GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo
```

y necesito que muestre esos datos para poder crear un arreglo de 21 y poder crear un grafico con esos datos.

Adjuntare la relación de la tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien me puede orientar o ayudar como poder obtener esos datos.

```html
CREATE TABLE `form_alumnos` (
  `id_form_alumno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cod_curso_alumno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `anio_ingreso` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `ua` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `cursos` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET ucs2 COLLATE ucs2_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `seccion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `anio` set('2015','2016','2017','2018','2019') NOT NULL,
  `semestre` set('Primer','Segundo') NOT NULL,
  `id_encuesta_for` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `form_alumnos`
--

INSERT INTO `form_alumnos` (`id_form_alumno`, `cod_curso_alumno`, `anio_ingreso`, `ua`, `cursos`, `seccion`, `anio`, `semestre`, `id_encuesta_for`) VALUES
(1, 342139, 2012, 53, 'IN1083C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(2, 342139, 2011, 53, 'IN1083C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(3, 342139, 2011, 53, 'IN1083C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(4, 342139, 2011, 53, 'IN1083C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(5, 342139, 2011, 53, 'IN1083C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(6, 342139, 2011, 53, 'IN1083C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(7, 354945, 2012, 54, 'IN1228C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(8, 354945, 2012, 54, 'IN1228C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(9, 354945, 2012, 54, 'IN1228C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(10, 354945, 2012, 54, 'IN1228C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(11, 354945, 2012, 54, 'IN1228C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(12, 354945, 2012, 54, 'IN1228C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1),
(14, 354945, 2012, 54, 'IN1228C', 1, '2016', 'Primer', 1);
```

```html
CREATE TABLE `preguntas` (
  `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_dimension_p` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `preguntas`
--

INSERT INTO `preguntas` (`id_pregunta`, `nombre`, `id_dimension_p`) VALUES
(1, 'Trabajar en esta actividad me permitió poner en práctica conceptos teóricos vistos en clases en ésta u otras asignaturas.', 1),
(2, 'Pude apreciar la importancia de utilizar métodos y/o herramientas de la disciplina en el desarrollo de la actividad.', 1),
(3, 'Para entender el problema y proponer una solución tuve que buscar y analizar información de diferentes fuentes.', 2),
(4, 'Tuve la posibilidad de tomar decisiones y defenderlas ante mi equipo de trabajo.', 2),
(5, 'Para el éxito de la actividad de aprendizaje servicio tuve que trabajar de forma permanente y perseverar en el logro de los objetivos. ', 2),
(6, 'Esta actividad me ayudó a ser flexible y mejorar mi capacidad para adaptarme a los cambios.', 2),
(7, 'Trabajar en esta actividad me permitió identificar las fortalezas y debilidades de mis conocimientos técnicos.', 2),
(8, 'Esta actividad permitió darme cuenta de la importancia del autoaprendizaje en mi desarrollo profesional.', 2),
(9, 'Para el logro de los objetivos de la actividad  requerí gestionar de forma adecuada el tiempo y los recursos.', 2),
(10, 'Trabajar con la comunidad me permitió valorar la importancia del comportamiento ético en mi profesión.', 2),
(11, 'El desarrollo de esta actividad me fomentó mi compromiso con el respeto hacia los otros participantes.', 2),
(12, 'Trabajar con el socio comunitario me permitió vincularme con profesionales o personas de otras áreas y realidades.', 2),
(13, 'A través de esta actividad pude darme cuenta de la importancia de poder trabajar en equipo.', 3),
(14, 'A través de esta actividad pude mejorar mis competencias en comunicación oral y escrita.', 3),
(15, 'El uso de las tecnologías de información y comunicación (TIC’s) favoreció el logro de los objetivos de la actividad.', 3),
(16, 'Tener definidos roles y responsabilidades de los integrantes del equipo de trabajo, fue fundamental para el desarrollo de la actividad.', 4),
(17, 'El desarrollo de esta actividad permitió darme cuenta del impacto de mi disciplina en la sociedad y medioambiente.', 4),
(18, 'A través de esta actividad pude conocer diferentes culturas organizacionales.', 4),
(19, 'Pude entender las necesidades del socio comunitario y a partir de ellas definir metas.', 4),
(20, 'La planificación, control y evaluación del desarrollo de la actividad favoreció el logro de los objetivos.', 4),
(21, 'Esta actividad permitió desarrollar mi capacidad de emprender e innovar.', 4);
```

```html
CREATE TABLE `tipo_respuesta` (
  `id_tipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` set('1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tipo_respuesta`
--

INSERT INTO `tipo_respuesta` (`id_tipo`, `id_pregunta`, `tipo`) VALUES
(100, 20, '5'),
(99, 20, '4'),
(98, 20, '3'),
(97, 20, '2'),
(96, 20, '1'),
(95, 19, '5'),
(94, 19, '4'),
(93, 19, '3'),
(92, 19, '2'),
(91, 19, '1'),
(90, 18, '5'),
(89, 18, '4'),
(88, 18, '3'),
(87, 18, '2'),
(86, 18, '1'),
(85, 17, '5'),
(84, 17, '4'),
(83, 17, '3'),
(82, 17, '2'),
(81, 17, '1'),
(80, 16, '5'),
(79, 16, '4'),
(78, 16, '3'),
(77, 16, '2'),
(76, 16, '1'),
(75, 15, '5'),
(74, 15, '4'),
(73, 15, '3'),
(72, 15, '2'),
(71, 15, '1'),
(70, 14, '5'),
(69, 14, '4'),
(68, 14, '3'),
(67, 14, '2'),
(66, 14, '1'),
(65, 13, '5'),
(64, 13, '4'),
(63, 13, '3'),
(62, 13, '2'),
(61, 13, '1'),
(60, 12, '5'),
(59, 12, '4'),
(58, 12, '3'),
(57, 12, '2'),
(56, 12, '1'),
(55, 11, '5'),
(54, 11, '4'),
(53, 11, '3'),
(52, 11, '2'),
(51, 11, '1'),
(50, 10, '5'),
(49, 10, '4'),
(48, 10, '3'),
(47, 10, '2'),
(46, 10, '1'),
(45, 9, '5'),
(44, 9, '4'),
(43, 9, '3'),
(42, 9, '2'),
(41, 9, '1'),
(40, 8, '5'),
(39, 8, '4'),
(38, 8, '3'),
(37, 8, '2'),
(36, 8, '1'),
(35, 7, '5'),
(34, 7, '4'),
(33, 7, '3'),
(32, 7, '2'),
(31, 7, '1'),
(30, 6, '5'),
(29, 6, '4'),
(28, 6, '3'),
(27, 6, '2'),
(26, 6, '1'),
(25, 5, '5'),
(24, 5, '4'),
(23, 5, '3'),
(22, 5, '2'),
(21, 5, '1'),
(20, 4, '5'),
(19, 4, '4'),
(18, 4, '3'),
(17, 4, '2'),
(16, 4, '1'),
(15, 3, '5'),
(14, 3, '4'),
(13, 3, '3'),
(12, 3, '2'),
(11, 3, '1'),
(10, 2, '5'),
(9, 2, '4'),
(8, 2, '3'),
(7, 2, '2'),
(6, 2, '1'),
(5, 1, '5'),
(4, 1, '4'),
(3, 1, '3'),
(2, 1, '2'),
(1, 1, '1'),
(105, 21, '5'),
(104, 21, '4'),
(103, 21, '3'),
(102, 21, '2'),
(101, 21, '1');
```

```html
CREATE TABLE `respuesta` (
  `id_respuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_form_alumno_fk` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `respuesta`
--

INSERT INTO `respuesta` (`id_respuesta`, `id_tipo`, `id_form_alumno_fk`) VALUES
(1, 4, 1),
(2, 9, 1),
(3, 14, 1),
(4, 19, 1),
(5, 21, 1),
(6, 29, 1),
(7, 34, 1),
(8, 39, 1),
(9, 43, 1),
(10, 49, 1),
(11, 54, 1),
(12, 56, 1),
(13, 64, 1),
(14, 69, 1),
(15, 75, 1),
(16, 78, 1),
(17, 85, 1),
(18, 89, 1),
(19, 94, 1),
(20, 99, 1),
(21, 103, 1),
(22, 4, 2),
(23, 8, 2),
(24, 14, 2),
(25, 19, 2),
(26, 23, 2),
(27, 28, 2),
(28, 34, 2),
(29, 39, 2),
(30, 44, 2),
(31, 49, 2),
(32, 54, 2),
(33, 58, 2),
(34, 64, 2),
(35, 69, 2),
(36, 74, 2),
(37, 79, 2),
(38, 83, 2),
(39, 88, 2),
(40, 93, 2),
(41, 99, 2),
(42, 103, 2),
(43, 5, 3),
(44, 10, 3),
(45, 15, 3),
(46, 20, 3),
(47, 24, 3),
(48, 30, 3),
(49, 34, 3),
(50, 40, 3),
(51, 45, 3),
(52, 50, 3),
(53, 55, 3),
(54, 60, 3),
(55, 65, 3),
(56, 70, 3),
(57, 75, 3),
(58, 80, 3),
(59, 85, 3),
(60, 90, 3),
(61, 95, 3),
(62, 100, 3),
(63, 105, 3),
(64, 4, 4),
(65, 10, 4),
(66, 14, 4),
(67, 20, 4),
(68, 25, 4),
(69, 30, 4),
(70, 35, 4),
(71, 39, 4),
(72, 44, 4),
(73, 50, 4),
(74, 55, 4),
(75, 59, 4),
(76, 65, 4),
(77, 69, 4),
(78, 74, 4),
(79, 79, 4),
(80, 84, 4),
(81, 89, 4),
(82, 95, 4),
(83, 100, 4),
(84, 105, 4),
(85, 5, 5),
(86, 10, 5),
(87, 14, 5),
(88, 20, 5),
(89, 25, 5),
(90, 29, 5),
(91, 34, 5),
(92, 39, 5),
(93, 44, 5),
(94, 50, 5),
(95, 54, 5),
(96, 59, 5),
(97, 64, 5),
(98, 69, 5),
(99, 75, 5),
(100, 79, 5),
(101, 84, 5),
(102, 90, 5),
(103, 94, 5),
(104, 99, 5),
(105, 105, 5),
(106, 5, 6),
(107, 10, 6),
(108, 15, 6),
(109, 20, 6),
(110, 25, 6),
(111, 30, 6),
(112, 35, 6),
(113, 40, 6),
(114, 45, 6),
(115, 50, 6),
(116, 55, 6),
(117, 60, 6),
(118, 65, 6),
(119, 70, 6),
(120, 75, 6),
(121, 80, 6),
(122, 85, 6),
(123, 89, 6),
(124, 94, 6),
(125, 99, 6),
(126, 104, 6),
(127, 4, 7),
(128, 9, 7),
(129, 14, 7),
(130, 19, 7),
(131, 24, 7),
(132, 29, 7),
(133, 34, 7),
(134, 39, 7),
(135, 43, 7),
(136, 49, 7),
(137, 54, 7),
(138, 58, 7),
(139, 64, 7),
(140, 69, 7),
(141, 74, 7),
(142, 79, 7),
(143, 84, 7),
(144, 89, 7),
(145, 94, 7),
(146, 99, 7),
(147, 103, 7),
(148, 5, 8),
(149, 10, 8),
(150, 15, 8),
(151, 20, 8),
(152, 25, 8),
(153, 30, 8),
(154, 35, 8),
(155, 40, 8),
(156, 45, 8),
(157, 50, 8),
(158, 55, 8),
(159, 60, 8),
(160, 65, 8),
(161, 70, 8),
(162, 75, 8),
(163, 80, 8),
(164, 84, 8),
(165, 89, 8),
(166, 95, 8),
(167, 100, 8),
(168, 105, 8),
(169, 4, 9),
(170, 9, 9),
(171, 14, 9),
(172, 18, 9),
(173, 24, 9),
(174, 29, 9),
(175, 34, 9),
(176, 39, 9),
(177, 44, 9),
(178, 49, 9),
(179, 55, 9),
(180, 59, 9),
(181, 65, 9),
(182, 69, 9),
(183, 74, 9),
(184, 79, 9),
(185, 84, 9),
(186, 89, 9),
(187, 95, 9),
(188, 99, 9),
(189, 104, 9),
(190, 4, 10),
(191, 10, 10),
(192, 14, 10),
(193, 20, 10),
(194, 25, 10),
(195, 29, 10),
(196, 35, 10),
(197, 39, 10),
(198, 44, 10),
(199, 49, 10),
(200, 54, 10),
(201, 58, 10),
(202, 64, 10),
(203, 70, 10),
(204, 75, 10),
(205, 80, 10),
(206, 84, 10),
(207, 88, 10),
(208, 93, 10),
(209, 99, 10),
(210, 104, 10),
(211, 5, 11),
(212, 10, 11),
(213, 14, 11),
(214, 19, 11),
(215, 25, 11),
(216, 30, 11),
(217, 34, 11),
(218, 39, 11),
(219, 45, 11),
(220, 49, 11),
(221, 55, 11),
(222, 59, 11),
(223, 65, 11),
(224, 69, 11),
(225, 74, 11),
(226, 80, 11),
(227, 84, 11),
(228, 88, 11),
(229, 94, 11),
(230, 99, 11),
(231, 103, 11),
(232, 5, 12),
(233, 10, 12),
(234, 14, 12),
(235, 19, 12),
(236, 23, 12),
(237, 29, 12),
(238, 33, 12),
(239, 40, 12),
(240, 44, 12),
(241, 50, 12),
(242, 55, 12),
(243, 59, 12),
(244, 64, 12),
(245, 68, 12),
(246, 74, 12),
(247, 79, 12),
(248, 84, 12),
(249, 87, 12),
(250, 95, 12),
(251, 99, 12),
(252, 102, 12),
(253, 5, 14),
(254, 10, 14),
(255, 15, 14),
(256, 20, 14),
(257, 25, 14),
(258, 30, 14),
(259, 35, 14),
(260, 40, 14),
(261, 45, 14),
(262, 50, 14),
(263, 55, 14),
(264, 60, 14),
(265, 65, 14),
(266, 69, 14),
(267, 75, 14),
(268, 80, 14),
(269, 84, 14),
(270, 89, 14),
(271, 95, 14),
(272, 100, 14),
(273, 105, 14);
```

Comment: Y no puede ser que alguno de los datos que tenga haga que se elimine justamente esas filas? va a ser dificil saberlos sin ver los datos...

Comment: ¿Esta segura que existe el registro de id_Pregunta = 2,6,16,17 en la tabla preguntas?, sería importante como indica gbianchi poder observar los registros de las tablas

Comment: Me parece que [estás duplicando pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/117720/29967), si hubieses puesto tus `CREATE TABLE` ya habríamos ensayado los datos y determinado dónde está el problema. Al ser varias tablas es más difícil animarse a crearlas uno mismo para reproducir el problema y analizar el código.

Comment: editare la la pregunta para insertar los create table son varios datos

Comment: acabo de incorporar los CREATE TABLE 
Saludos

Comment: Claudia, el problema se encuentra en esta condición: `f.cod_curso_alumno = '354945'`. Las preguntas que no aparecen, no cumplen ninguna con esa condición.  Si quitamos esa condición y agregamos la columna `f.cod_curso_alumno` al SELECT, tendrás todos los datos y en el caso de la pregunta con id `2` y las otras, tendrás `NULL` en la columna `f.cod_curso_alumno`.

Comment: Lo puedes probar con esta consulta: `SELECT  p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, f.cod_curso_alumno, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas
FROM preguntas p
LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta
LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo
LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno
WHERE  (f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer' 
       or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL) AND (tr.tipo = '3') 
GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, r.id_tipo;`

Comment: Considero que hay un grave error de diseño en tu base de datos, entre otras cosas, porque haces una relación *ficticia* entre la tabla alumnos y la tabla respuestas, sin pasar por la tabla encuesta... (es así como aparece en tu imagen). Luego de este comentario te propondré que hagas una consulta casi igual a la tuya, pero quitando las condiciones relativas a la tabla `form_alumnos`. Cuando veas los resultados te vas a asustar, porque en el valor de `cod_curso_alumno` por el que tú quieres filtrar sólo aparecen **¡tres filas!** con `354945`. Por eso digo que los datos son *ficticios*.

Comment: Esta es la consulta de que la te hablo, sólo he quitado esto del WHERE: `f.cod_curso_alumno = '354945'`...  **`SELECT  p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, f.cod_curso_alumno, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas
FROM preguntas p
LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta
LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo
LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno
WHERE  (f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer' 
       or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL) AND (tr.tipo = '3') 
GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, r.id_tipo;`**

Comment: En la consulta que me diste tienes razón aparecen 3 filas con el filtro **354945** debe haber un error el cual debería solucionar , entonces debería hacer la consulta pasando por la tabla encuesta hasta llegar a la tabla respuesta(aunque una vez lo hice y no me resulto ) lo voy a intentar, por que necesito hacer el filtro por el **f.cod_curso_alumno** para poder llegar a las respuesta de ese curso en especifico

Comment: que me consejas que haga sobre la estructura de las tablas para lograr los resultados que necesito @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0):

La consulta parece menos ficticia si aplicamos las relaciones como las tienes en la imagen compartida.

La veracidad o no de los resultados dependerá de los datos que tengas.

Yo he creado las tablas que faltaban:  `encuesta`, `dimension` y he agregado datos *ad libitum*.

Al final te dejo el enlace para que hagas pruebas.

En la consulta he quitado los `NULL` forzados que tú querías evaluar. Si el diseño está bien, el uso de `LEFT JOIN` te dará `NULL` si alguna condición del `JOIN` no se cumple.

Si esto no resuelve tu problema, entonces debes explicar con claridad qué pretende tu programa y se podría revisar el diseño.

La consulta escrita así:

```
SELECT  
p.id_pregunta, 
tr.tipo, 
f.cod_curso_alumno, 
COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas
FROM form_alumnos f 
LEFT JOIN encuesta e ON f.id_encuesta_for=e.id_encuesta 
LEFT JOIN dimension d ON e.id_encuesta = e.id_encuesta 
LEFT JOIN preguntas p ON d.id_dimension = p.id_dimension_p 
LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta
LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo
WHERE  (f.cod_curso_alumno = '354945' AND f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer') 
AND (tr.tipo = '3') 
GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, r.id_tipo;
```

Arroja este resultado:

```
id_pregunta     tipo    cod_curso_alumno    cantidad_respuestas
1               3       354945              0
2               3       354945              7
3               3       354945              0
4               3       354945              7
5               3       354945              14
6               3       354945              7
7               3       354945              7
8               3       354945              0
9               3       354945              14
10              3       354945              0
11              3       354945              0
12              3       354945              21
13              3       354945              0
14              3       354945              7
15              3       354945              0
16              3       354945              7
17              3       354945              7
18              3       354945              21
19              3       354945              14
20              3       354945              0
21              3       354945              28
```

---

Desde el siguiente enlace puedes hacer pruebas si lo deseas: <kbd>[**VER DEMO DEL CÓDIGO**](http://rextester.com/PESH10690)</kbd>

Comment: ya había aplicado esa consulta y arrojaban los mismo resultados que te salieron a ti, ese caso no hace el filtro por que todo las respuesta y los multiplica por 7 que es la cantidad de alumno que respondieron en **354945** .

Comment: Mi proyecto se trata de un modulo de encuesta, 
los alumnos de un curso deben llenar un pequeño(form_alumno) y luego se redirecciona a la encuesta(escala de likert).
Por la otro lado, el administrador puede gestionar los datos de las encuestas y poder filtrar por cursos en un gráfico de barra 100% apilada.

Yo creo el problema esta en el diseño, pero tantas veces que he visto el diseño no se ocurre una mejora por el momento.

Comment: ´SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas
FROM encuesta e LEFT JOIN dimension d on e.id_encuesta = d.id_encuesta_p
LEFT JOIN preguntas p on d.id_dimension = p.id_dimension_p
LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo
LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno
WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '354945' AND f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer'  or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL) AND (tr.tipo = '3') GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo´

Comment: pero me arroja la misma tabla. 
Como dices tu tendré que rediseñar las tablas por que ya nose donde cambiar bien los datos

Comment: @claudia24 Sería cuestión de **comprender** lo que quieres hacer y proponerte un diseño. Pero ahora mismo es para mí imposible detenerme en esto, quizá mañana puedo dedicarle un rato a lo más difícil, que es *comprender* lo que quieres hacer. De alguna manera he interpretado en la consulta lo que vi en tu diseño, pero si los resultados no son los esperados significa que : A. El diseño es erróneo, o B. Los datos que hay actualmente en las tablas son erróneos. Ambas cosas son difíciles de determinar para quien no ha diseñado la BD.